# Data sharding seems not work properly with tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, distributed-tensorflow

I have a model trained under `tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()`, which could be run without errors. However, the training time doesn't decrease as expected compared with training with single-worker.

I checked some details and there're two main things which I suspect there should be something wrong with the autoshard:

1. Each worker are caching all of the data from my data source.
2. The outputs per epoch shows a strange accuracy value of 1.9, which is exactly the sum of accuracy on two workers. (checked with 3 workers and accuracy is close to 3 then)

I turn off the `shuffle` as suggested on [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/input#caveats) when using `tf.data.Dataset.list_files` , but the problem remains.